# How to align text in a row using bootstrap classes?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

```css
.list-group-item{
  width: 165px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 1px;
  text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 1px;
margin-top: 58px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="list-group" v-if="showSearchHistory">
        
            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory.slice(-5).reverse().map(s => s.trim( ))"
            :key="index"
              @click="selectPreviousSearch(index)">{{ item }}</li>
          </ul>
```

I have two bootstrap classes namely "list-group-item" and "list-group". So i have a doubt that. for bootstrap classes there are some pre styles will be automatically added. So in this case

i want to align all the text in a single row(side by side), instead of one by one. (From the li, i am getting text when button clicked, )

Comment: display: inline-block for li items

Comment: try to add 'd-flex' on the `list-group` if you are using bootstrap or use `display: flex` on the `list-group`

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.list-group{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.list-group> li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

can you use this option?

Comment: Tried changing but still same no change

Comment: I think need to target on two bootstrap class like list-group-item and list-group

Answer (score -1):

Add `list-style: none;` to the list and `display: inline` or `float: left` to each of the list items

See this example:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_menu

Comment: use `inline-block` instead of `inline`. `float`is a property for floating images within a paragraph only. It is not intended for styling purpose. It was mis-used as a hack befor 2012 with the introduction of HTML5 and flexbox aswell as css-grid. Now in 2021 (9 years later) you still should use flex instead.

Comment: btw. thats a reason why w3schools has a mixed reputation. It teaches many outdated hacks instead of state-of-the-art methods.

Comment: Well you could use css flexbox or grid which are the easiest methods and the most used ones in 2021. But not all rendering engines use HTML5 (outlook desktop app email rendering engine doesn't understand HTML5). So you could call these legacy but they will get the job done with being compatible with old engines and if responsiveness and best practices are not concerns

Comment: So if the purpose is creating a template

Comment: then you wouldnt use CSS... nor a navigation bar.

Comment: So if the purpose is creating a website, both methods could be used and you should use HTML5, if not you migh end up using HTML2.

Comment: read again. With HTML5 you have modern techniques that you should use. You dont need to relay on outdated HTML4 techniques such as mis-using float as hack. Espacially if you still elarnign HTML5 and CSS3 you should elarn the modern techniques instead of doing outdated methods that will slow down your progress.

Comment: Read again. Sometimes HTML5 is an option. And true when you know modern techniques you should use them If possible. But when you are learning it's better to know more than HTML5

Comment: what you mean know more then HTML5? Who still sues HTML4 or 3? Even then its not rocketsince. HTML4 just has a lot of outdated tags then know handled by CSS instead (or alternativly inline-style). There is no browser or E-Mail server that does not support HTML5.